# Is a lambda expression from this possible?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I know

```
from f in list 
where f.bar == someVar
select f
```

can be written as

```
list.Where( f => f.bar == someVar );
```

Can a similar expression be created from

```
from f in foo
from b in f.bar
where b.something == someVar
select b;
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from` maps (for subsequent terms) to `SelectMany`:

```
var query = foo.SelectMany(f=>f.bar).Where(b=>b.something==someVar);
```

(note that no final `Select` is necessary for trivial projections)

Comment: Dude. You can't possibly be human. You must be some kind of Android :-)

Comment: @Jose: [whirr] Does not compute. Repeat query from start.