# Is this lambda expression possible?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Thanks to the help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795483/is-a-lambda-expression-from-this-possible).

Tried this, without luck..

I know

```
from f in list 
where f.bar == someVar
select f
```

can be written as

```
list.Where( f => f.bar == someVar );
```

Can a similar expression be created from

```
from f in foo
from b in f.bar
where b.something == someVar
select f;
```

?

Edit: 
Sorry, I forgot f.bar in the second example is a list of objects.

Comment: Can you explain why Marc Gravell's answer didn't work? It should work. Also, try to reply there instead of asking the same question twice.

Comment: This post is different than the other. Do not vote it down.

Comment: It's not duplicate. `select b` -> `select f` will make a difference.

Comment: @Mehrdad Sorry didn't see the select f vs select b.

Comment: I've added further explanation in the question. Sorry bout the confusion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Nathan W: Not an issue. In fact I edited my code 3 times to get to the right one :)) I kept not noticing details.

Comment: @sre: My updated answer should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely. Query syntax is just a syntactic sugar. It'll be translated to underlying lambda syntax by the compiler, so every query expression has an equivalent lambda based representation.

This is probably what you need (this is not strictly equivalent to that but works when you just have one `bar` matching the query in each `foo`):

```
var result = foo.Where(f => f.bar.Any(b => b.something == someVar));
```

The strictly equivalent version is:

```
var result = foo.SelectMany(f => f.bar, (f, b) => new { F = f, B = b })
                .Where(x => x.b.something == someVar)
                .Select(x => x.f);
```